# Can I manipulating certain amount of rows without adding extra index column on data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I am wondering if I can operate the data on data.table by certain numbers of rows, like every 5 rows? I can do this by adding an extra index column and obtain the result as follow. I am wondering if I can do the same thing without adding index column, since my data has millions of rows, adding a new column, just eat up the memory. Thanks for the advice.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(A = 1:20, B = sample(1000, 20), C = sample(10, 20, replace = T))

# Can I work on the DT, and get the result as following, 
# without adding extra column D, like DT.1?

DT.1 <- cbind(DT, D=rep(1:5, each=4))

DT.1[, .(MeanA=mean(A), MeanB=mean(B), MeanC=mean(C)), by="D"][,.(MeanA, MeanB, MeanC)]
#   MeanA  MeanB MeanC
#1:   2.5 688.50  4.50
#2:   6.5 656.00  4.25
#3:  10.5 610.50  8.75
#4:  14.5 451.75  5.50
#5:  18.5 423.00  4.75
```

Comment: You dont need to `cbind`, this can be done within the `by` itself  `DT[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = .(D = rep(1:5, each = 4))][, D := NULL][]`

Comment: You can also check whether a `split` combine works better or not `rbindlist(lapply(split(DT, rep(1:5, each = 4)), function(x) x[, lapply(.SD, mean)]))`

Comment: @akrun That looks answer-worthy. Btw, I guess `by=` is less memory intensive than `split` (size of largest group vs size of entire table).

Comment: @Frank I will check if the OP comes back with some benchmarks.

Comment: Thanks, @akrun, seems you are talking an anonymous function within data.table by using "by=". Great!

Comment: @Grec001  In the first one, there is no anonymous call.  It is the second one and as @Frank mentioned, it could be costly with `split`

Comment: @akrun if there was a reward to the personal supporter, I'll vote for you for sure.